# TDD: Constructor Injection and Mutator Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

It's time for some more seemingly simple questions that I just can't seem to find the answer to.

I'm developing a library with TDD (PHP). To my understanding, when using TDD, **you should not write any production code without first writing a failing test to warrant it**.

1. I have a mutator method, that appends data to an array with private visibility. How should I test that? Should I just test the various accessor instead? Should the test for the accessor cover the mutator method?
2. Is it OK for a test to test an accessor and a mutator, or should these be separate tests?
3. My library requires a dependency, which I will inject through the constructor. What test code might prompt me to write the constructor code?

Sorry for such noobish questions. I've been studying TDD quite a lot, and thought I had it all figured out, but as soon as I try to make use of it, all these little questions come to mind. Obviously I want to make sure that, I implement it effectively and to the best of my knowledge.

Perhaps I'm being too strict? Perhaps the injection is tested implicitly using a mock and checking expectations of a method that makes use of the injected class?

I understand these questions might be subjective, and the answers might be based on people's opinions, but I'm fine with that. I just want to get started in a way that makes sense and works.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just my answer to 3: "Perhaps the injection is tested implicitly using a mock and checking expectations of a method that makes use of the injected class?" Yes, that's how I do it.

Comment: And personally, I test setter+getter together, since there's no other way (I won't try to access the private property, that test would blow up if the implementation changed). But I'm interested to know if alternatives/better ways exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test the setter and getter methods together, because that is by far the simplest way to do it without having to change the visibility of your array, which you shouldn't do. Your injected class will be tested implicitly by these tests.

In general try to write your unit tests from the perspective of another user trying to use your class under test. You need to think, what is this class supposed to do or what is its contract (i.e. this class holds an array of objects that users can add and remove from), then write tests to be certain it satisfies that contract. After that, write just enough code to get the test to pass.